# Join two tables with exact matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, qsqlquery

i want to join 2 tables with a varchar column and my condition is to join rows by its exact matched values.
suppose 
table 1 :

### id   colname1                    name

1      sample text value(developer)    ram1 
2      sample text value-coding           jeena

table 2 :

### id   colname2                            name2

1      sample text value-green developer    vinu 
2      sample text value-coding issues        mohan

I need a result like

### id   colvalue1                           colvalue2                               name1     name2

1      sample text value(developer)          sample text value-green developer         ram1    vinu 
2      sample text value-coding       sample text value-coding issues                         jeena   mohan

ie join columns with exact match records

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Do you have some C# code already that has the data? If so, please include enough so someone can help answer it.

Comment: uh... join on the ID? and name?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1):

An INNER JOIN will select records that have matching values in both tables.

So in your case, you will want to join the 'id'. To get exactly the results in your example, use the following query:

```
SELECT
     1.colname1 [colvalue1]
    ,2.colname2 [colvalue2]
    ,name
FROM 
    table_1 AS 1
INNER JOIN
    table_2 AS 2 ON 1.id = 2.id
```

Comment: i want to join 2 tables with columns colname1,colname2      in ON condition

Comment: What's the condition? You can include an ADD statement with the condition after the JOIN type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the SQL to do that, it will be something like this:

```
SELECT COLVALUE1, COLVALUE2, NAME FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.NAME = B.NAME2
```

But you should get some research on joins, it would be the first link on google.

Comment: Bro,i want to join 2 tables with columns colname1,colname2      in ON condition